# Heroku deployment hangs on executing DB queries, then fails with Timed out running buildpack Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, heroku, sequelize.js

When the server starts locally it shows the same log and there's no problem with that, but heroku throws a time out error after about half an hour after Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `tickets`. Please help me find a solution if you know what could cause heroku to time out

**Build log:**

```
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version 12.x...
       Downloading and installing node 12.16.2...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.4

-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)

       > bcrypt@3.0.8 install /tmp/build_e646d1e4649549b3146de47b32344538/node_modules/bcrypt
       > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

       [bcrypt] Success: "/tmp/build_e646d1e4649549b3146de47b32344538/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" is installed via remote

       > nodemon@2.0.2 postinstall /tmp/build_e646d1e4649549b3146de47b32344538/node_modules/nodemon
       > node bin/postinstall || exit 0

       Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
        > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate

       added 1555 packages from 835 contributors and audited 1218380 packages in 46.698s

       29 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details

       found 42573 vulnerabilities (42538 low, 21 moderate, 14 high)
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

-----> Build
       Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts
       Running heroku-postbuild

       > haste@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_e646d1e4649549b3146de47b32344538
       > concurrently "npm run ts-server" "npm run dev-webpack" "npm run server"

       [1] 
       [1] > haste@1.0.0 dev-webpack /tmp/build_e646d1e4649549b3146de47b32344538
       [1] > webpack --open --config webpack.dev.js
       [1] 
       [0] 
       [0] > haste@1.0.0 ts-server /tmp/build_e646d1e4649549b3146de47b32344538
       [0] > tsc -w -p ./src/server/tsconfig.json
       [0] 
       [2] 
       [2] > haste@1.0.0 server /tmp/build_e646d1e4649549b3146de47b32344538
       [2] > nodemon public/server/app.js
       [2] 
       [2] [nodemon] 2.0.2
       [2] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
       [2] [nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
       [2] [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
       [2] [nodemon] starting `node public/server/app.js`
       [0] c12:09:50 PM - Starting compilation in watch mode...
       [0] 
       [1] 
       [1] webpack is watching the files...
       [1] 
       [2] Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
       [2] Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (`id` INTEGER UNSIGNED auto_increment , `firstName` VARCHAR(128), `lastName` VARCHAR(128), `email` VARCHAR(128), `department` VARCHAR(128), `password` VARCHAR(128), `role` VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT 'member', `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
       [2] Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tickets` (`id` INTEGER UNSIGNED auto_increment , `title` VARCHAR(128), `department` VARCHAR(128), `priority` VARCHAR(128), `deadline` DATETIME, `description` VARCHAR(1024), `date` DATETIME, `assignee` VARCHAR(128), `status` VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT 'unassigned', `assigneeID` INTEGER UNSIGNED, `initiatorId` INTEGER UNSIGNED, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`assigneeID`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY (`initiatorId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;
       [2] Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Session` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `sid` VARCHAR(1024), `expires` DATETIME NOT NULL, `data` VARCHAR(1024), `userId` INTEGER UNSIGNED, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;
       [2] Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (`id` INTEGER UNSIGNED auto_increment , `firstName` VARCHAR(128), `lastName` VARCHAR(128), `email` VARCHAR(128), `department` VARCHAR(128), `password` VARCHAR(128), `role` VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT 'member', `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
       [2] DB connected
       [2] Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `users`
       [2] Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `tickets`
       [2] Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `Session`
       [2] Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `users`
       [2] Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Session` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `sid` VARCHAR(1024), `expires` DATETIME NOT NULL, `data` VARCHAR(1024), `userId` INTEGER UNSIGNED, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;
       [2] Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `Session`
       [2] Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tickets` (`id` INTEGER UNSIGNED auto_increment , `title` VARCHAR(128), `department` VARCHAR(128), `priority` VARCHAR(128), `deadline` DATETIME, `description` VARCHAR(1024), `date` DATETIME, `assignee` VARCHAR(128), `status` VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT 'unassigned', `assigneeID` INTEGER UNSIGNED, `initiatorId` INTEGER UNSIGNED, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`assigneeID`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY (`initiatorId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;
       [2] Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `tickets`
       [2] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
       [1] Hash: eb67f2c1e3b2e96c43ee
       [1] Version: webpack 4.41.6
       [1] Time: 16192ms
       [1] Built at: 04/27/2020 12:10:08 PM
       [1]              Asset      Size    Chunks             Chunk Names
       [1]     bundle-home.js  48.5 KiB      home  [emitted]  home
       [1] bundle-register.js  19.3 KiB  register  [emitted]  register
       [1]   bundle-signin.js  18.2 KiB    signin  [emitted]  signin
       [1] Entrypoint home = bundle-home.js
       [1] Entrypoint signin = bundle-signin.js
       [1] Entrypoint register = bundle-register.js
       [1] [./src/client/js/Modals.ts] 4.65 KiB {home} [built]
       [1] [./src/client/js/auth.ts] 2.26 KiB {signin} [built]
       [1] [./src/client/js/cardTicketsContent.ts] 874 bytes {home} [built]
       [1] [./src/client/js/collapsableCards.ts] 1.36 KiB {home} [built]
       [1] [./src/client/js/dropdowns.ts] 839 bytes {home} [built]
       [1] [./src/client/js/fetchData.ts] 441 bytes {home} {signin} {register} [built]
       [1] [./src/client/js/home.ts] 810 bytes {home} [built]
       [1] [./src/client/js/register.ts] 2.08 KiB {register} [built]
       [1] [./src/client/js/ticketClass.ts] 370 bytes {home} [built]
       [1] [./src/client/js/ticketStatus.ts] 359 bytes {home} [built]
       [1] [./src/client/js/ticketTake.ts] 1.01 KiB {home} [built]
       [1] [./src/client/js/userClass.ts] 457 bytes {register} [built]
       [1] [./src/client/js/utilitiesHome.ts] 421 bytes {home} [built]
       [2] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
       [2] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
       [2] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
       [2] [nodemon] starting `node public/server/app.js`
       [2] Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
       [2] Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (`id` INTEGER UNSIGNED auto_increment , `firstName` VARCHAR(128), `lastName` VARCHAR(128), `email` VARCHAR(128), `department` VARCHAR(128), `password` VARCHAR(128), `role` VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT 'member', `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
       [2] Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tickets` (`id` INTEGER UNSIGNED auto_increment , `title` VARCHAR(128), `department` VARCHAR(128), `priority` VARCHAR(128), `deadline` DATETIME, `description` VARCHAR(1024), `date` DATETIME, `assignee` VARCHAR(128), `status` VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT 'unassigned', `assigneeID` INTEGER UNSIGNED, `initiatorId` INTEGER UNSIGNED, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`assigneeID`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY (`initiatorId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;
       [2] Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Session` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `sid` VARCHAR(1024), `expires` DATETIME NOT NULL, `data` VARCHAR(1024), `userId` INTEGER UNSIGNED, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;
       [2] Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (`id` INTEGER UNSIGNED auto_increment , `firstName` VARCHAR(128), `lastName` VARCHAR(128), `email` VARCHAR(128), `department` VARCHAR(128), `password` VARCHAR(128), `role` VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT 'member', `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
       [2] DB connected
       [2] Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `users`
       [2] Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `tickets`
       [2] Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `Session`
       [2] Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `users`
       [2] Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Session` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `sid` VARCHAR(1024), `expires` DATETIME NOT NULL, `data` VARCHAR(1024), `userId` INTEGER UNSIGNED, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;
       [2] Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `Session`
       [2] Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tickets` (`id` INTEGER UNSIGNED auto_increment , `title` VARCHAR(128), `department` VARCHAR(128), `priority` VARCHAR(128), `deadline` DATETIME, `description` VARCHAR(1024), `date` DATETIME, `assignee` VARCHAR(128), `status` VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT 'unassigned', `assigneeID` INTEGER UNSIGNED, `initiatorId` INTEGER UNSIGNED, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`assigneeID`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY (`initiatorId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;
       [2] Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `tickets`
       [2] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
       [2] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
       [2] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
       [2] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
       [2] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
       [2] [nodemon] starting `node public/server/app.js`
       [2] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
       [2] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
       [2] [nodemon] starting `node public/server/app.js`
       [2] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
       [2] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
       [2] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
       [2] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
       [2] [nodemon] starting `node public/server/app.js`
       [2] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
       [2] [nodemon] starting `node public/server/app.js`
       [0] 
       [0] 12:10:15 PM - Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
       [2] Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
       [2] Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (`id` INTEGER UNSIGNED auto_increment , `firstName` VARCHAR(128), `lastName` VARCHAR(128), `email` VARCHAR(128), `department` VARCHAR(128), `password` VARCHAR(128), `role` VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT 'member', `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
       [2] Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tickets` (`id` INTEGER UNSIGNED auto_increment , `title` VARCHAR(128), `department` VARCHAR(128), `priority` VARCHAR(128), `deadline` DATETIME, `description` VARCHAR(1024), `date` DATETIME, `assignee` VARCHAR(128), `status` VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT 'unassigned', `assigneeID` INTEGER UNSIGNED, `initiatorId` INTEGER UNSIGNED, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`assigneeID`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY (`initiatorId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;
       [2] Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Session` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `sid` VARCHAR(1024), `expires` DATETIME NOT NULL, `data` VARCHAR(1024), `userId` INTEGER UNSIGNED, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;
       [2] Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (`id` INTEGER UNSIGNED auto_increment , `firstName` VARCHAR(128), `lastName` VARCHAR(128), `email` VARCHAR(128), `department` VARCHAR(128), `password` VARCHAR(128), `role` VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT 'member', `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
       [2] DB connected
       [2] Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `users`
       [2] Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `tickets`
       [2] Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `Session`
       [2] Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `users`
       [2] Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Session` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `sid` VARCHAR(1024), `expires` DATETIME NOT NULL, `data` VARCHAR(1024), `userId` INTEGER UNSIGNED, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;
       [2] Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `Session`
       [2] Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tickets` (`id` INTEGER UNSIGNED auto_increment , `title` VARCHAR(128), `department` VARCHAR(128), `priority` VARCHAR(128), `deadline` DATETIME, `description` VARCHAR(1024), `date` DATETIME, `assignee` VARCHAR(128), `status` VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT 'unassigned', `assigneeID` INTEGER UNSIGNED, `initiatorId` INTEGER UNSIGNED, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`assigneeID`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY (`initiatorId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;
       [2] Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `tickets`
-----> Timed out running buildpack Node.js
Terminated
/app/tmp/buildpacks/a104ebb80184ba556a3457859a381585c1c182694d8086bfcdabe39f3fe5857835812b209be5647b385deaddf7afa081b0f0c5d9d1683b767fb8abc0c3b79cc0/lib/monitor.sh: line 1: kill: (1802) - No such process
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Can you try to connect your heroku database with your local machine and do some transactions and see if it works ?

Comment: Please share your `package.json`. I suspect that the post-build script mistakenly runs your app.

Comment: @elight ty for your reply, here's my package.json:
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "dev-webpack": "webpack --open --config webpack.dev.js",
    "prod-webpack": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "server": "nodemon public/server/app.js",
    "ts-server": "tsc -w -p ./src/server/tsconfig.json",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run ts-server\" \"npm run dev-webpack\" \"npm run server\"",
    "build": "concurrently \"npm run prod-webpack\" \"npm run server\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "concurrently \"npm run ts-server\" \"npm run dev-webpack\" \"npm run server\""
  },

Comment: Remember you can edit your question, which means in this case you can properly format this as code. It's difficult to read accurately in a comment. I'll take a look at this once it is added to your question. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit